# I cannot properly configure PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have spent the last four hours reading examples, watching YouTube videos etc and I cannot for the life of me get an email to send.  I have tried using a G-mail account with the settings changed to allow for less secure apps and also a privately hosted email address from my business.

I loaded PHPMailer with composer

When I use the following code which is literally the example from PHPMailer's github page, I get the errors listed below.

```
  <?php

  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

  require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

  try {
      //Server settings
      $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
      $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
      $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       //Set the SMTP server to send through
      $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
      $mail->Username   = 'my gmail email here';                  //SMTP username
      $mail->Password   = 'my gmail password here';               //SMTP password
      $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
      $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`
  
      //Recipients
      $mail->setFrom('my gmail email address', 'Mailer');
      $mail->addAddress('different email address', 'Joe User');     //Add a recipient


      //Content
      $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
      $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
      $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
      $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
  
      $mail->send();
      echo 'Message has been sent';
  } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
  }
```

This is the error message that I get:
2021-08-09 20:04:25 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

I am 100% sure that the email addresses and passwords are correct and listed in the proper locations.

Does anyone know what is going on or what I can do to fix?

I am so desperate I am about to just switch programming languages because this is the most insanely complicated thing I have ever came across!

Thanks so much to anyone that has a solution or tips!

PS I am currently using localhost... I will answer any questions that you need answered Thanks!!!

UPDATE >>>
When I change to this line

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION;
```

I get this output:

2021-08-09 21:02:10 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array()
2021-08-09 21:02:10 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed [C:\xampp\htdocs\sheri\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 388]
2021-08-09 21:02:10 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto [C:\xampp\htdocs\sheri\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 388]
2021-08-09 21:02:10 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unknown error) [C:\xampp\htdocs\sheri\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 388]
2021-08-09 21:02:10 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: _"I am so desperate I am about to just switch programming languages"_ Note this issue  has nothing to do with PHP. "SMTP connect failed" means that your server can't connect to Google's server. It's likely that your hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP connection attempts in order to prevent spamming. What host are you using? Can you do `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465` from a command line and get a response header?

Comment: So you managed to spend 4 hours completely ignoring the link in the error message that points you directly at detailed descriptions of how to diagnose this exact problem?

Comment: @AlexHowansky  I wrote that because its own mail function is worthless and phpmailer seems to have the monopoly on mailers.

Comment: @AlexHowansky  When I ran that in command prompt I got "'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."    As I stated in my post, I am using localhost at the moment

Comment: I mean "what host" as in, where is your server hosted? Is it GoDaddy?

Comment: Check who you're talking to. I'm the maintainer of PHPMailer and I've answered over 1,000 questions on PHPMailer (including many duplicates of yours) on SO. If you followed that link, why did you not include the results of your tests in your question that you insist has never happened to anyone before?

Comment: @AlexHowansky My private email is hosted on namecheap.com but as I stated, I get the exact same message when using Gmail settings as they are in the example.

Comment: If you don't follow the advice in the guide, and don't post your results, there's not really anything we can do to help you; we're flying blind.

Comment: You misunderstand. What hosting provider provides the server that this code is running on?

Comment: I changed to this line and added the output in the question

Comment: $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION;

Comment: Finally! It's amazing what can happen when you read the docs. Now you have a useful error message: *certificate verify failed*. Now go read [this](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure), which describes how to diagnose this problem. Short version: it's likely your CA certificate bundle is outdated, or your ISP is redirecting your SMTP traffic. It's easier to diagnose this if you temporarily switch to STARTTLS for encryption (`SMTPSecure = 'tls'` and `Port = 587`), as the docs describe.

Answer (score 1):

When I changed `SMTPSecure = 'tls'` and `Port = 587` this still did not work in local host but did work when I uploaded it on my server to test it.

Answer (score 0):

> SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) SMTP connect() failed

That implies a firewall issue - but its actually rather misleading.

> SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Your PHP installation could not validate the certificate presented by Google. They are usually quite good with certificates - its an issue with the installation of openssl on your machine. You need to configure openssl properly, specifically the [CAcerts database](https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.configuration.php).

**update**
You installed MS-Windows on a namecheap VM and are using it as a webserver?????? OMG.